# Using named ranges with embedded formulas for excel chart data

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have two drop-down menus that list a range of dates. One date identifies the beginning of the range and the other the end. I also created two named ranges as follows:

```
chart_Dates=INDEX(Dates,MATCH(Home!$A$7,Dates,0)):INDEX(Dates,MATCH(Home!$A$9,Dates,0))
chart_Frequency=INDEX(Frequency,MATCH(Home!$A$7,Dates,0)):INDEX(Frequency,MATCH(Home!$A$9,Dates,0))
```

`Dates`, and `Frequency` from those formulas are named ranges with set boundaries. If I manually enter the y-values as "Home!chart_Frequency" and the horizontal values as `Home!chart_Dates` the macro works just fine. I can adjust the start and end dates using the drop-down menus and the graph updates accordingly.

However, the macro recorder doesn't translate those action into code. I've attempted the following code without success (there is no error generated but the graph only references the first cell in my range).

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("chart_Frequency")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("chart_Dates")
```

How do I get the code to replicate what I can do manually? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: supplement the range references with parent worksheet references.

Comment: while I applaud the integration of your dynamic named ranges, why aren't you applying the same logic to a true and full vba solution?

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Names(1).Name ThisWorkbook.Names(1).Value You can loop ThisWorkbook.Names to get all your named ranges.

Comment: @Jeeped I'm still a novice as far as this is concerned. Most of that work is a combination of macro recording, trial and error, google searches, and help from others. What do you mean by a full vba solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub testing()
    Dim freqRange As String
    Dim datesRange As String
    Dim Name As Variant
    For Each Name In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Name.Name = "chart_Frequency" Then
            freqRange = Name.Value
        ElseIf Name.Name = "chart_Dates" Then
            datesRange = Name.Value
        End If
    Next Name
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!$B$1"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = datesRange
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = freqRange
End Sub
```

My chart didnt have any series so it adds a new series and it updates the Name, Values and XValues with no issues.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the input! I gave that a shot. At first I got a compile error stating that "Name" needed to be defined. I defined "Name" as a variant and the macro ran. Unfortunately, when I check the y-values in the graph it is blank (that's a first). Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: I have edited my answer with something i just tested.

Comment: I just tried again with the same result. It's has to be an issue with the rest of my code. I'll send my code over in case I missed something. Thank you again! I'm on day three of trying to figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have right now. After it runs when I check the y-values and horizontal values on the graph itself and they are both blank.

```
'Create chart
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As ChartObject

'Data range for the chart
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("$E$7:$F$501")

'Designates which cell to place the top left corner of the graph in
ActiveSheet.Range("N5").Select

'Create a chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
Width:=360, _
Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
Height:=216)

'Give chart some data
'I was using the line below to set the range but comment blocked it out and entered the suggested code
'  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
Dim freqRange As String
Dim datesRange As String
Dim Name As Variant
For Each Name In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If Name.Name = "chart_Frequency" Then
        freqRange = Name.Value
    ElseIf Name.Name = "chart_Dates" Then
        datesRange = Name.Value
    End If
Next Name
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Home!$A$5"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = datesRange
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = freqRange

'Determine the chart type
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkersStacked

'Remove Major Gridlines
cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete

'Sets the legend to the bottom of the graph
cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
cht.Name = "Frequency_Chart"

'Add title and reference A5 for name
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Frequency_Chart").Activate
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Caption = "=Home!R5C1"
```